Contraction between two fields in the Interaction and Heisenberg picture
The m-point correlator is (including interaction):
\begin{equation*}
\langle{\Omega|}\mathcal{T}\left(\phi_{H}\left(t_{m} \right)\phi_{H}\left(t_{m - 1}\right) ... \phi_{H}\left(t_{1} \right) \right){|\Omega}\rangle = \frac{\langle{0|} \mathcal{T}\left(\phi_{I}\left(t_{m} \right) \phi_{I}\left(t_{m - 1} \right) ... \phi_{I}\left(t_{1} \right)S \right){|0}\rangle}{\langle{0|}S{|0}\rangle}
\end{equation*}
The letter $H$ denotes the operator in the Heisenberg picture, while $I$ is used for the interaction picture.
The matrix $S$ is:
\begin{equation*}
S = \displaystyle \lim_{T \to \infty} \mathcal{T}\left(e^{-i\int_{-T}^{T} V\left(t'\right)dt'} \right)
\end{equation*}
Consider the following interaction:
\begin{equation*}
V\left(t\right) = \frac{\lambda}{4!}\phi^{4}\left(t\right)
\end{equation*}
Let's compute $\langle{0|}S{|0}\rangle$ up to first order:
\begin{equation*}
\langle{0|}S{|0}\rangle = 1 + \displaystyle \lim_{T \to \infty} - \frac{i\lambda}{4!}\int_{-T}^{T}\langle{0|}\mathcal{T}\left(\phi_{I}\left(t'\right) \phi_{I}\left(t'\right) \phi_{I}\left(t'\right) \phi_{I}\left(t'\right) \right){|0}\rangle dt'
\end{equation*}
$\langle{0|}\mathcal{T}\left(\phi_{I}\left(t'\right) \phi_{I}\left(t'\right) \phi_{I}\left(t'\right) \phi_{I}\left(t'\right) \right){|0}\rangle $ can be computed by using Wick's theorem. The normal-ordered terms vanish, and only the terms with two contractions contribute. There are three possible ways to contract. The equation reduces to:
\begin{equation*}
\langle{0|}S{|0}\rangle = 1 + \displaystyle \lim_{T \to \infty} - \frac{i\lambda}{8}\int_{-T}^{T}\langle{0|}\mathcal{T}\left(\phi_{I}\left(t'\right) \phi_{I}\left(t'\right)\right){|0}\rangle dt'
\end{equation*}
My question is, why is the contraction between two scalar fields in the Interaction picture the same as for two fields in the Heisenberg picture?
$\langle{0|}\mathcal{T}\left(\phi_{I}\left(t'\right) \phi_{I}\left(t'\right)\right){|0}\rangle = \langle{0|}\mathcal{T}\left(\phi_{H}\left(t'\right) \phi_{H}\left(t'\right)\right){|0}\rangle = D_{F}\left(t' - t'\right) = D_{F}\left(0\right)$

The reason for this is because $\phi_I(t, \vec{x})$ has the exact same form as $\phi_H(t,\vec{x})$, since $\phi_I(t,\vec{x})$ obeys the free Klein-Gordon equation.
To avoid repetition, I will just refer you to:
Why are fields in the interaction picture the same as free fields in the Heisenberg picture?
which contains a detailed description.
